# An error occurs when running the launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running autoware NDT in auto_ map_ Publisher, rviz2 reports an error:Message Filter dropping message: frame ' ' at time 0.000 for reason 'EmptyFrameID'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399498/an-error-occurs-when-running-the-launch-file/) by [marks](https://answers.ros.org/users/100829/marks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marks](https://answers.ros.org/users/100829/marks/) on 2022-04-24**:
How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this could be a relevant issue: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/1440

> The main issue for me was the point
> cloud fields. It doesn't work when I
> have the intensity field. My map only
> worked after I removed the intensity
> field.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marks](https://answers.ros.org/users/100829/marks/) on 2022-04-24**:
Thank you. This problem has bothered me for a long time. Now it has been solved. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-25**:
I have added more context for future readers. If this is the correct answer, please upvote and accept it so others can see that it has been answered :)